# DSSS error code 65280

Tags: d, tango, dsss

I have a pomodoro timer that I am trying to compile using DSSS. It compiles when executing:

```
dmd pomodoro.d
```

However, when I execute

```
dsss build
```

From within the project directory, it complains:

```
pomodoro.d => pomodoro
WARNING: Module pomodoro.d does not have a module declaration. This can cause problems
         with rebuild's -oq option. If an error occurs, fix this first.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltango
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
Command /opt/dsss/bin/rebuild returned with code 65280, aborting.
Error: Command failed, aborting.
```

My dsss.conf file in the directory is:

```
name = pomodoro
[pomodoro.d]
target = pomodoro
```

The contents of  /opt/dsss/etc/rebuild/default is

```
profile=dmd-posix-tango
```

I think the offending line is here(in dmd-posix-tango), but do not know what to do.

```
[link]
oneatatime=yes
cmd=dmd -L--start-group -L-ltango $i -of$o
```

This is on Arch Linux

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSSS is no longer maintained. Consider using dub: http://code.dlang.org/